# Laravel: 'A non-numeric value encountered' when trying to concatenate string

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a form and controller, and most of my fields save correctly, however, I have an issue with my 'duration' column.

I have three fields:
  *mod_start_time

  mod_finish_time

  mod_duration*

And in my code I have a store function with these three lines:

```
$mod->mod_start_time = Input::get('mod_start_time_hour'.'mod_start_time_minute');
$mod->mod_finish_time = Input::get('mod_finish_time_hour'.'mod_finish_time_minute');
$mod->mod_duration = Input::get('mod_finish_time_hour'.'mod_finish_time_minute' - 'mod_start_time_hour'.'mod_start_time_minute');
```

The variables that they receive inputs from (in the form) are:
*mod_start_time_hour

mod_start_time_minute

mod_finish_time_hour

mod_finish_time_minute*

The first two lines of code appear to parse correctly, where the mod_start_time_hour and mod_start_time_minute are concatenated and saved to the database. However, the third line doesn't save correctly, with a non-numeric value being encountered.

I initially thought the problem was that the variables were being saved as a string so I changed the database so that mod_start_time, mod_finish_time and mod_duration are all integers. However, even after change the types of these three variables, the issue still occurred.

My question is, am I concatenating it incorrectly, or using the subtraction operator incorrectly, and if I am, how do I rectify this?

EDIT ONE: To clarify, I have two different strings,
*'mod_finish_time_hour'.'mod_finish_time_minute'

'mod_start_time_hour'.'mod_start_time_minute'*

which have been concatenated together, and now I'm trying to subtract the 'start' concatenated string from the 'finish' concatenated string in order to get the duration, hence:
('mod_finish_time_hour'.'mod_finish_time_minute')  - ('mod_start_time_hour'.'mod_start_time_minute')

EDIT TWO: As mod_start_time_hour and mod_start_time_minute are both integers, it is possible to concatenate two integers, or do I have to convert them to string before I can?

Comment: just focus on perfect concatenate. near Desk["-"] you doesnt concatenate perfectly.. correct it.

Comment: in duration you put desk sign [ - ] or minus sign. there is a problem.. `'mod_finish_time_minute' - 'mod_start_time_hour'` in this statement. you put minus sign but both strings are not join.. syntax problem

Comment: The '-' is intentionally there, I'm trying to subtract the second value from the first in order to return the duration.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is concatenate two seperate strings, and then subtract one from the other, which is why the '-' sign is there.

Comment: then first you need to translate string type to integer type then it might be work

Comment: All the variables are already in the integer format in the database, as they've been declared that way, do I have to redeclare them as integers in the code to get it to work?

Comment: for substraction you need to convert `'mod_finish_time_hour'.'mod_finish_time_minute'` this one and `'mod_start_time_hour'.'mod_start_time_minute'` this one into integer.. there is possible that it take it as string and problem occur..

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Post the same values passed as the inputs. I'll help you out. Btw even the first 2 lines are wrong, the values being set would be null. Since you're doing the concatenation inside wrong.

Comment: The values being passed to get the current error is fed via a dropdown, so for mod_start_time_hour/mod_start_time_minute, I put in 09 . 00 and for mod_finish_time_hour/mod_finish_time_minute I put in 15 . 00. Thanks for the catch for the first two lines btw, I just realised! Do you know what I'm doing wrong?